# Indent wrapped lines using less

Tags: linux, less

Using less you can wrap long lines with `-S` or `--chop-long-lines`.

Is there any way to indent those wrapped lines?

Comment: To be clear, the `chop-long-lines` option in `less` turns OFF line wrapping. As far as I know, this is not possible in `less`. It is somewhat possible in `vim` if you do `:set showbreak=>>>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that such an option exists.

You should rather be using the
[indent command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/indent)
which will give a much more readable text.

See especially all options relating to "Breaking Long Lines".
There is also a section in the man-page with this same name.